# rEFInd does not show macOS boot icon

Tags: macos, startup, unix, efi, grub

I have a MacBook Pro 15" late 2015, on whom I created two partitions on the main SSD, on one there is the macOS, and on the other I installed Linux Mint. As boot manager I installed rEFInd.

Yesterday I accidentally reinitialized the disk on which Linux was installed, and when I restarted the Mac, in the rEFInd boot menu there was no more the icon to load macOS, but only the one for Linux. Selecting that one, it loads into the Minimal Grub Bash, from which I don't know how to proceed.
I'm also unable to boot into safe mode at start, I assume because it loads rEFInd before macOS operating system is loaded.

What could I do to load macOS again, or get in a macOS shell from where I could probably remove the rEFInd solving the problem and being able to boot to macOS?

I actually need only to take some important data from the disk, moving it for example to an external drive, after that I can also restore the Mac Book. So if there is any way, like hardware, to get to the data on the disk I would appreciate a lot your help.

Comment: Hold the alt-key while booting to try to get to the macOS boot menu or boot to Internet/Recovery Mode (either alt-cmd-R or cmd-R).

Comment: I get to the internet recovery mode. How can I from there then boot to macOS? Should I try to delete rEFInd or is there some command to reset the efi, or directly load the operative system?

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the internet recovery mode, make sure you are connected directly to your internet router via an ethernet cable.

What you could do is hold the following key combinations first.
Shift-Option-Command-R, this will bring you to install the MacOS on your Mac HD.

But you could first refresh NVRAM before resetting your system:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Option</kbd>  + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> => Hold all these 4 keys at startup, and you'll be able to enter into your macOS, and do the necessary fixes from there...